# How do I write this shortcode?

Tags: shortcode

I have this shortcode, I would like to write in a better and clean way:

```
function webhosting_products_shortcode( $atts, $content = null) {
    $content='<h2 class="heading_blue">Eburnie Hosting vous offre:</h2>'
            . '<div class="hostingbox"><dl>'
            . '<dt><a href="http://hosting.eburnienetwork.com/web-hosting/index.php">Hébergement Web</a></dt>'
            . '<dd class="img"><img src="img/gamlastan.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="Gamla Stan" /></dd>'
            . '<dd>Hébergement Web</dd></dl>'
            . '<dl  class="alt"><dt><a href="http://hosting.eburnienetwork.com/web-hosting/email-hosting.php">Hébergement Email</a></dt>'
            . '<dd class="img"><img src="img/gamlastan.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="Gamla Stan" /></dd>'
            . '<dd>Hébergement Email</dd></dl>'
            . '<dl><dt><a href="http://hosting.eburnienetwork.com/website-design/index.php">Conception de Sites</a></dt>'
            . '<dd class="img"><img src="img/gamlastan.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="Gamla Stan" /></dd>'
            . '<dd>Conception de Sites</dd></dl>'
            . '<dl><dt><a href="http://hosting.eburnienetwork.com/digital-ssl-certificate/index.php">Certificat SSL</a></dt>'
            . '<dd class="img"><img src="img/gamlastan.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="Gamla Stan" /></dd>'
            . '<dd>Certificat SSL</dd></dl>'
            . '<dl><dt><a href="http://hosting.eburnienetwork.com/reseller-hosting.php">Programme Revendeur</a></dt>'
            . '<dd class="img"><img src="img/gamlastan.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="Gamla Stan" /></dd>'
            . '<dd>Programme Revendeur</dd>'
            . '</dl></div>';

    return $content;       
}
add_shortcode('webhosting', 'webhosting_products_shortcode');
```

The shortcode [webhosting] is working, but I don´t think it´s the right way to achieve it.
Thanks.

Comment: Close voted as there is no way to correctly answer this question, and nothing that could be considered a 'correct' answer. It is too subjective

Answer (score 1):

```
function webhosting_products_shortcode( $atts, $content = null) {
    ob_start();
    include('shortcodecontent.php');
    $shortcode = ob_get_clean();
    return $shortcode;
}
add_shortcode('webhosting', 'webhosting_products_shortcode');
```

Improvements include:

- Your html is now in a separate file, and can be written as is, rather than as a long PHP string
- Trailing whitespace is bad, untidy, and should be highlighted by your code editor to point out the waste